# How to use namespaces when using XSD to validate a XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to understand how I can validate an XML file with an XSD.
I don't quite understand the namespaces.

If I have the code:

```
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.Load(file.InputStream);
    xDoc.Schemas.Add("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", @"C:MyXSD.xsd");

    ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);
    xDoc.Validate(eventHandler);
```

I get the Error:
"The target namespace of an attribute declaration, whether local or global, must not match http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance."

What should I be setting the namespace to when I add the schema to the xDoc?

I have an xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rootNode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    // My Nodes
</rootNode>
```

and I created an XSD from that XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="rootNode">
   // My Nodes
  </xsd:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scenario you can just pass null as the namespace to Schemas.Add, as you are not actually using namespaces, i.e. your XML document does not use a namespace (which would be specified either with the xmlns attribute or the use of a namespace prefix).

For more information on namespaces please see http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp.

Note that http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance is a namespace used to define schema attributes that relates only to the schema infrastructure and not your specific XML schema.